postgresql.conf not found when installed via homebrew
Installed Versions

Homebrew 4.4.13
PostgreSQL 14.15

As the log says
Dumindus-MacBook-Pro:bin jayedumindu$ brew info postgresql
==> postgresql@14: stable 14.15 (bottled)
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
Installed
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.15 (3,328 files, 45.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-12-25 at 15:03:10
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/p/postgresql@14.rb
License: PostgreSQL
==> Dependencies
Build: pkgconf ✘
Required: icu4c@76 ✔, krb5 ✔, lz4 ✔, openssl@3 ✔, readline ✔
==> Caveats
This formula has created a default database cluster with:
  initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14

To start postgresql@14 now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql@14
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
==> Analytics
install: 49,752 (30 days), 172,407 (90 days), 596,982 (365 days)
install-on-request: 49,123 (30 days), 169,965 (90 days), 582,478 (365 days)
build-error: 61 (30 days)

When cd into the installation path : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.15
Dumindus-MacBook-Pro:14.15 jayedumindu$ ls 
COPYRIGHT               homebrew.postgresql@14.service
HISTORY                 include
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json            lib
README                  sbom.spdx.json
bin                 share

There is no such configuration file, also the data directory where the actual page files are stored is not mentioned. Where to find them?
I have tried searching for a directory called
/usr/local/var/postgres/

and it was not found!

The log extract says it set up an installation in
/opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14

You wouldn't expect to find config files in the binaries path would you? Not sure why you looked there.

My bad! I completely ignored that section
This formula has created a default database cluster with:   initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
